# Multi Index Dirac delta function

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If we assume the following result:
$$\delta^{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots , \alpha_k, \rho}_{\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots , \beta_k, \rho} = (n-k)\delta^{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots , \alpha_k}_{\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots , \beta_k}$$

Apparently I'm supposed to show

$$\delta^{\rho_1,\rho_2,\cdots , \rho_k}_{\rho_1,\rho_2,\cdots , \rho_k} = (n-k+1)\cdots (n)$$

But I keep getting $=(n-k+1)\cdots (n-1)$.

As a concrete example, consider
$$\delta^{\rho_1,\rho_2}_{\rho_1, \rho_2}=(n-1)\delta_{\rho_1}^{\rho_1}=(n-1)\neq n$$

Comment: What you should "keep getting" is $(n-k+1)\cdots (n-1)\delta_{\rho_1}^{\rho_1}$. If $\delta_{\rho_1}^{\rho_1}=n$ you are done.

Comment: "As a concrete example", consider that
$\delta^{\rho_1,\rho_2}_{\rho_1, \rho_2}=(n-1)\delta^{\rho_1}_{\rho_1}$.

Comment: So the heart of the matter is to know what is $\delta_\rho^\rho$. You think that $\delta_\rho^\rho=1$ and your textbook uses the identity $\delta_\rho^\rho=n$. Since you do not explain what the notation $\delta_\rho^\rho$ refers to, you will have to decide this for yourself.

Comment: Well $\delta_{\rho_1}^{\rho_1}=1$ because this is just the ordinary delta tensor.  The multi version is defined as the determinant of the matrix formed by making the entries all possible ordinary deltas that have one lower and one upper index on (respectively from the multi index list)

Comment: Ah! I think I see my issue.... I forgot I'm using Einstein notation! So obviously, $\delta_{\rho_1}^{\rho_1}=n$. But now I have a meta question... should I delete this post now that I answered my own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the recommendation of a comment, I'll answer this.

In general $\delta^j_i$ is $1$ if $j=i$ and $0$ otherwise.

In general, if we write the same symbol we sum over that symbol.

If we write the same symbol, the two symbols are obviously equal but if we don't write the same symbol they may or may not be equal to each other.

With these ideas in mind, we easily see that $\delta_i^i= n$